# Listview with TextView and EditText per line

Tags: java, android, listview, textview, android-edittext

I have to come to you for assistance with a particular activity in my android application. I would like to have a list of item descriptions with a `textfield` next to it. This `textfield` is used to put in a quantity.

I am thinking about doing this by using a listview with a custom row layout but am wondering wether or not this is the right way to go for this.

I will fill the list from code since these items are fetched from a webservice.

So what is the best way to accomplish this? Use a listview or use a different view? Can I write to my domain object after the edittext editing was finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the example of what I've done for my current project.

```
//java for my class 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class editpage extends ListActivity {
    int editCount;
    private dbadapter mydbhelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.edit_list);
        mydbhelper = new dbadapter(this);
        mydbhelper.open();
        fillData();
    }



    private void fillData() {


        Cursor e = mydbhelper.getUserWord();
            startManagingCursor(e);

     // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (TITLE,DATE,NUMBER)
        String[] from = new String[] {dbadapter.KEY_USERWORD,};

        // an array of the views that we want to bind those fields to (in this case text1,text2,text3)
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textType,};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
       SimpleCursorAdapter editadapter = 
       new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.edit_row, e, from, to);
       ListView list = getListView();
       View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, list, false);
       list.addFooterView(footer);
       setListAdapter(editadapter);
       editCount = e.getCount();
        }

        public void onClick(View footer){
            final MediaPlayer editClickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button50);
                editClickSound.start();
                    };


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(list, v, position, id);
    //final Intent intent = new Intent(this, title.class);
    //startActivityForResult(intent, position);
    }
```

Then for my cursor, note that I have multi where statements. I do this bc I have a multi lvl listview. categories ->source -> title -> user word.

```
    // retrieves all the descriptions for the edittext fields
      public  Cursor getUserWord() 
        {
            return myDataBase.query(USER_WORD_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ID, 
                    KEY_CATEGORY,
                    KEY_SOURCE, KEY_TITLE, KEY_EDITWORD, KEY_USERWORD 
                    }, 
                    KEY_CATEGORY+ "=" + categories.categoryClick + " AND " + KEY_SOURCE+ "=" 
                    +source.sourceClick + " AND " + KEY_TITLE+ "=" + title.titleClick, 
                    null, null, null, KEY_ID);

        }
```

Lastly I have my xml to display this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"/>

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_gravity="left">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textType"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:text="spaceholder" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="160dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:height="25dip">
        </EditText>

</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirminedit"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:text="@string/confirmbutton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Last XML is for a footer with a confirm button. So after the user fills the edittext it will take the data and store it for the next activity to use. This function is what I'm currently working on but this code should give you a good idea on what you asked about.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are talking about is to create ListView with focusable EditText inside it.

For the same you need to create a custom adapter for listview, create a raw layout with one EditText and inflate the same for every row by creating an adapter class.

Detailed example is here: [Android Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

Comment: That was what I was thinking, but is this the best practice? I have not seen anything similar on android so far.

Comment: @BartVanRemortele It depends on what kind of your requirement is.